How to recursively calculate all paths to a terminal state in an iterated system with two state variables?
Compute the number of ways to reach the terminal state (A = 1) using recursion.
Consider an iterated system with two state variables A and B.

A can have a values of 0 or 1

B can have a value of 0,1,2,3 ог 4


The variables are initialized to (A,B) = (0,2). At each iteration, one of the two state variables can transition to one adjacent allowed values, i.e. for A 0 --> 1, 1-->0. For B, a value of 2 can transition as 2-->1 or 2-->3.
A terminal state is reached for A=1.
How many different ways are there to reach the terminal state after maximum iterations? I am supposed to write a method that computes this number recursively!
Example (A initial position ,B initial position, Current Step, Maximum Step) = (0,2,0,1) = 1
Here's my try:
def recurse(A, B, step, max_step):
    if A == 1:
        return 1
    if step > max_step:
        return 0
    ways = 0
    if A == 0:
        ways += recurse(1, B, step + 1, max_step)
    if B > 0:
        ways += recurse(A, B - 1, step + 1, max_step)
    if B < 4:
        ways += recurse(A, B + 1, step + 1, max_step)
    return ways

But as can be seen in this table, it fails:



Input
Expected Output
Actual Output




(0,2,0,1)
1
1


(0,2,0,2)
2
3


(0,2,0,3)
4
7




Why is the expected output for (0,2,0,2) equal to 2? I see these paths: (0,2)->(0,1)->(1,1), (0,2)->(0,3)->(1,3), and (0,2)->(1,2). Which one of the these three should not be counted, and why?

What does "after maximum iterations" mean? Does it mean "after at most max_step iterations"?

See https://studyx.ai/homework/101689439-considet-an-iterated-system-with-two-stale-variables-a-and-b-acan-have-a-values-of-o-or-1   - it appears to mean “after EXACTLY max_it iterations”. The poster here has mis-posted the problem.

@trincot you are right for (0,2,0,2) there are 3 way but expected is 2, even I am also confused about that's why put this question on this platform

If you cannot explain why you expect a certain output, then this question is at a dead end. We cannot help with that. We can help with programming problems, not with a contradiction between your specifications and your expected output. That just means your specifications are wrong, or your expected output is wrong, or both are wrong.

Any response to the other comments?

further actual output for your code is 3
7
13

You have mis-stated the question (see https://studyx.ai/homework/101689439-considet-an-iterated-system-with-two-stale-variables-a-and-b-acan-have-a-values-of-o-or-1 ). It must reach the final state at EXACTLY max_step stages (or, at least, when step==max_step). Thus, in trincot's example it is the last of the three that should not be counted, because this used just one step and not two.
Thus, the only thing wrong with your code is that you record a "success" automatically if A=1 (the termination state), whereas you should check that this occurs with the requisite number of steps. In your code change the line
return 1

to
return 1 if step == max_step else 0

This will then give you the desired output.

You can generally simplify the logic of your code. For example, with the B operations you can immediately return 0 if B<0 or B>4. With a bit of generalisation to more available states:
def recurse(A, B, step, max_step):
    Amin, Amax, Bmin, Bmax = 0, 1, 0, 4
    Atarget = 1
    if A < Amin or A > Amax or B < Bmin or B > Bmax: return 0
    if A == Atarget                                : return 1 if step == max_step else 0
    if step >= max_step                            : return 0
    return recurse( A - 1, B, step + 1, max_step) + recurse( A + 1, B, step + 1, max_step ) + recurse( A, B - 1, step + 1, max_step ) + recurse(A, B + 1, step + 1, max_step)

print( recurse( 0, 2, 0, 1 ) )
print( recurse( 0, 2, 0, 2 ) )
print( recurse( 0, 2, 0, 3 ) )

Output:
1
2
4


Perfect Answer, Thanks

Oops, you prematurely return when A == target even though more valid steps could be taken. You must invert the sequence of conditions if steps == max_steps: return 1 if A == Atarget else 0. The output should be 1, 4, 13

A is a “termination”. “Termination is final.

@lastchance the question also states "At each iteration, one of the two state variables can transition to one adjacent allowed values, i.e. for A 0 --> 1, 1-->0, ..."

Sure, but “termination” means end. If my train gets to a terminus, I get off it. I don’t see much point in writing code that gives outputs 1,4,13 when the question states that the expected outputs are 1, 2, 4.
